# Erro ao adidicionar a Controler no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net

Uma duvida ao criar uma *controller*.
Pois ao tentar criar a mesma tem apresentado o erro da imagem em anexo.

Criei 3 classes pequenas: `Dependentes`, `Tipobenef`, `TitularPlano` e `ProvaContext`

```
[Table("dependentes")]
public class Dependentes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    //public Tipobenef Tipo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TitularesPlano")]
    public int IdTitularPlano { get; set; }
    public virtual TitularPlano Titular { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tipobenef> Tipobenefs { get; set; }

}

public enum Tipobenef
{    
    Filho,
    Conjugue,
    Pai,
    Mae        
}

[Table("Titularesplano")]
public class TitularPlano
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(11)]
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string RG { get; set; }
}

public class ProvaContext:DbContext
{
    public ProvaContext():base("Prova")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<TitularPlano> Titulares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dependentes> Dependentes { get; set; }

}
```

---

Já aqui vai a parte do `WebConfig`:

```
<add name="Prova"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=Localhost\DESKTOP-T8VEK67; Initial Catalog=DbProva; Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

Em que já tentei também todos os nomes possíveis do `localhost`

**Imagem 1:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Imagem 2:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi, Bruno, existe um erro na declaração da sua chave estrangeira.

Você declara sua coluna e coloca a FK para a entidade designando a anotação para o atributo que faz a ligação. No caso você designou uma anotação que não existe no atributo errado.

```
...    
public int IdTitularPlano { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("IdTitularPlano")]
public virtual TitularPlano Titular { get; set; }
...
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo, funcionou.

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como solução. Qualquer coisa a comunidade está à disposição. Abraço.